# Difference(s) between named function & anonymous function (Lua)

Tags: functional-programming, lua

What is the differences between these `myFunc`s?

Code 1

```
function wrapper()
    local someVariable = 0;
    function myFunc(n)
        if n > 0 then return myFunc(n-1) end
    end
    return myFunc;
end
```

Code 2

```
function wrapper()
    local someVariable = 0;
    local myFunc = function(n)
        if n > 0 then return myFunc(n-1) end
    end
    return myFunc;
end
```

Code 3

```
function wrapper()
    local someVariable = 0;
    local myFunc;
    myFunc = function(n)
        if n > 0 then return myFunc(n-1) end
    end;
    return myFunc;
end
```

Because when I refer the function name `myFunc` inside the `myFunc` itself. Their behavior are not the same. (eg. the upvalue `someVariable`... problematic :-S )

Answer (score 5):

[edit: I misread your code #2.]

Code #1 sets the global value of `myFunc` to the function. So every time you call `wrapper`, you will be setting this one global to a new value. Furthermore, any references to your `myFunc` call will be to this global (which is modifiable), not to a local (which would be an upvalue of the closure).

Code #2 sets a local variable `myFunc`. ***However***, because of the rules of Lua, that local variable only comes into scope *after* the statement defining it is complete. This allows you to do things like this:

```
local x = x or 5
```

The `x` in the expression is a previously declared local or global. The new `x` doesn't come into scope until after the `x or 5` expression has been evaluated.

The same goes for your function definition. Therefore any references to `myFunc` will be to a *global variable*, not a local.

Code #3 creates a local variable `myFunc`. Then it sets into that variable a function. Because the function is created *after* the local variable comes into scope, references to `myFunc` in the function will refer to the local variable, not to a global one.

Note that `local function X` is equivalent to `local X; X = function...`. ***Not*** to `local X = function...`.

Comment: Thanks! So when I use `local function myFunc()` in code 1, all of them become identical?

Comment: @HKTonyLee: Actually, no. I completely misread your item #2. See my new version.

Answer (score 2):

Nicol's answer is mostly correct, but there is one thing that is worth pointing out:

In Code 2 `MyFunc` doesn't need to be a global variable, it can be a local variable in some outer scope, which will become an upvalue for this function you are creating (the same comment also applies to Code 1). For example, this will print `100`:

```
local function myFunc(n) return 100 end
function wrapper()
    local someVariable = 0;
    local myFunc = function(n)
        if n > 0 then return myFunc(n-1) end
    end
    return myFunc;
end
print(wrapper()(1))
```

So, to summarize, there are four ways you can use to define myFunc:

1. `local myFunc; myFunc = function(n) ... return myFunc(n-1) end`
2. `local function myFunc(n) ... return myFunc(n-1) end`
3. `local myFunc = function(n) ... return myFunc(n-1) end`
4. `myFunc = function(n) ... return myFunc(n-1) end`

1 and 2 are full equivalents. 3 will not do what you expect as it will use whatever definition of myFunc is available when `local myFunc` is executed (which may point to an upvalue for MyFunc or a global variable). 4 will work, but only because it will assign the newly created function to (again) either an upvalue or a global variable (and reference the same value in the body of the function).